# Golang how to install lib with go mod command

Tags: go

I searched some article, all they used this why:

```
$go mod init project_name
```

Then created main.go and coded these:

```
package main

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func main() {
 r := gin.Default()
 r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
     c.JSON(200, gin.H{
         "message": "pong",
     })
 })
 r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080 (for windows "localhost:8080")
}
```

then `go run main.go`

but in the fact, I can't remember the lib's full name like `"github.com/gin-gonic/gin"`, maybe I just remember `gin`.

So is there some way to install lib like python pip tool or `go get` like `go mod install gin`

---

PS:

because that I am using goland as my IDE, under the GOPATH, I can get the code tips, but under the go mod, I couldn't get it, Then I have started the question of this.

Comment: I usually copy the `github.com/gin-gonic/gin`  from the import.

Answer (score 2):

> ... but in the fact, I can't remember the lib's full name like "github.com/gin-gonic/gin", maybe I just remember gin.

> So is there some way to install lib like python pip tool or go get like go mod install gin[?]

⛔️ No.

If you don't know full name of the package you cann't `get` it.

You can try to use IDE's tips (*GoLand* as example IDE) to find a package without `<domain>/<owner>/...`, `import` full package name and use

```
go mod tidy
```

to modify `go.mod` file,*but* IDE will try to find package in you local cache.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules

The go *module* name is unique, so normally starts with domain name (unless it is a build-in module).

So just copy your *import* string's and run `go get` you will get it. e.g.

```
go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

To update a module, use `-u`:

```
go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so because some project have the same name, golang use project path system for your project. Usually yourhost/author/projectname, try googling your lib you try to remember with golang keyword e.g gin golang. Most of the time you will find it.

Answer (score -1):

> So is there some way to install lib like python pip tool or go get like go mod install gin [?]

No. That is not how Go works.